# Como verificar se existe um elemento dentro de uma lista?

Tags: c#, .net, lista

Preciso verificar se existe um estado na minha lista..estou passando um parâmetro (um código estado) e o método vai ver na lista se esse estado existe. Algo deste tipo em C#:

```
if (listState.Contains(s.nIDState) == estado)
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem:

```
return listState.Any(l => l.nIDState == estado);
```

[`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/bb337697(v=vs.100).aspx) é uma extensão de `Enumerable`. Ele verifica se existe pelo menos um ítem da lista que seja igual a `estado`, devolvendo `true`, ou `false` em caso contrário.

Comment: É isso mesmo que eu quero...vou testar agora e ja te falo valeu

Comment: Perfeito é isso mesmo deu certo aqui muito obrigado !

Comment: Fiz isso e deu certo também, vlw !

Answer (score 1):

Você está bem se usar o [`Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) do LINQ, mas se precisar de algo com mais eficiência ou quiser fazer algo mais específico pode usar um código especializado:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using static System.Console;

List<Exemplo> lista = new() {new() { nIDState = 2 }, new() { nIDState = 3 }};
WriteLine(Contains(lista, 2));
WriteLine(Contains(lista, 3));
WriteLine(Contains(lista, 4));
                    
static bool Contains(List<Exemplo> lista, int estado) {
    foreach (var item in lista) if (item.nIDState == estado) return true;
    return false;
}

class Exemplo {
    public int nIDState = 1;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://OznYyq). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4N71xw). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/Contains.cs).

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você quer saber se existe um elemento em uma lista em uma coluna Faça desta forma:

```
return listState.FindAll(l => l.nIDState == "estado");
```

O FindAll procura o que existe dentro de determinada coluna.

É bom para encontrar determinado item retornado de uma query do banco....