# Qual a forma mais eficiente de colocar objectos dentro de uma lista contida em um outro objecto?

Tags: c#

```
     public turma(string nomeTurma)
     {
                this.nomeTurma = nomeTurma;
                listaAlunos = new List<aluno>();
      }   

      public aluno(string nomeAluno, string dataDeNascimento, string nomeTurma)
        {
            this.nomeAluno = nomeAluno;
            this.dataDeNascimento = dataDeNascimento;
            this.nomeTurma = nomeTurma;

        } 


     public  List<aluno> listaAlunos;

     foreach (var item in turmas)
      {
         if (item.nomeTurma == novoAluno.NomeTurma)
         {
            item.listaAlunos.Add(novoAluno);
         }
     }
```

Estou a colocar alunos dentro da listaAlunos que é uma propriedade do objecto turma e para isso utilizei um foreach onde verifico se a turma que o aluno se registou ja existe criada e se esta existir eu vou colocar o aluno.

Existe alguma forma mais eficiente de fazer isto?

Não entende a questão comente abaixo que irei melhorar a questão.

Comment: Poderia postar como você está preenchendo os dados de `turmas` e `novoAluno`? Esses dados estão vindo de um banco de dados ou um formulário?

Comment: O código está um pouco esquisito, onde está esse `foreach`? Isso é uma tudo são classes diferentes, certo?, de onde surgiu esse `novoAluno`?

Comment: @Randrade os dados vêm de um formulário

Comment: @bigown novoAluno  = aluno novoAluno

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes Não sei se entendi. Você está trazendo a lista de turmas e o novo aluno de um formulário? Aproveitando, poderia postar o código do formulário?

Comment: @Randrade  https://pastebin.com/LggbPegP

Comment: Esse código não é o que está na pergunta.

Comment: @bigown https://pastebin.com/9yq8cpVj

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes Já pensou em fazer o `where` no `foreach()`? Algo tipo ` foreach (var item in turmas.Where(t => t.nomeTurma == novoAluno.NomeTurma))`

Comment: isso seria mais eficiente ?

Comment: Mas eficiente certamente não é, é mais conciso, mais declarativo, precisa ver qual é o objetivo. Está me parecendo que mais eficiente que o que fez não tem não, a não ser que toda estrutura da aplicação possa ser mudada, o que nem deve ser o caso. E se precisa dessa eficiência toda é outra questão.

Comment: @bigown e em vez de usar o foreach poderia usar o find ?

Comment: Não vejo como, nem está fazendo busca aí.

Comment: Por quê não utilizar o `.Any`? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32934/como-verificar-se-existe-um-elemento-dentro-de-uma-lista